# PHP String Manipulation and SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi still a beginner in php programming and one of the function of my project is to check if the schedule exist or not in the database. anyway my problem is that the way i created the string query, i am not sure if the string is correct in terms of syntax but the query is correct and tested in the phpmyadmin MySQL GUI.

```
$start_time = $_POST['Time-In'];
$end_time = $_POST['Time-Out'];
$procedure_date = $_POST['txbDateofProcedure'];

$DateStartTime = $procedure_date." ".$start_time;
$DateEndTime = $procedure_date." ".$end_time;

//Not sure but i think that the $Check-Schedule php syntax is incorrect
$Check_Schedule = "select * from appointment_dim where dentist_id = '$dentist_id'".
 "and (CONCAT(appoint_date, ,appoint_timein) between '$DateStartTime' and '$DateEndTime')".
    "OR (CONCAT(appoint_date, ,appoint_timeout) between '$DateStartTime' and '$DateEndTime')";

$result_schedule = mysql_query($Check_Schedule,$con);
if(!$result_schedule)
{
    trigger_error("Cannot located database".mysql_error());
   die();
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result_schedule) > 0)
{
    $SchedErrMesg = "The time you requested is already take try again.";
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$SchedErrMesg');</script>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Have you ran this program ?

Comment: I looks like the `PHP` syntax is correct but you should replace `CONCAT(appoint_date, ,appoint_timein)` with `CONCAT(appoint_date, ' ', appoint_timein)` to get a string with a space between date and time.

Comment: Are you facing any specific problem with the given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the delimiter between `appoint_date` and `appoint_time*` to be space, you should do this:

```
CONCAT(appoint_date, ' ', appoint_timein)
```

but not this:

```
CONCAT(appoint_date, , appoint_timein)
```

Also i believe u want the logic like

```
"dentist_id = x AND (timeBetween1 OR timeBetween2)"
```

But not that u wrote:

```
"(dentist_id = x AND timeBetween1) OR timeBetween2"
```

So try this:

```
$Check_Schedule = "
    SELECT * FROM appointment_dim 
    WHERE 
        dentist_id = '$dentist_id' 
        AND (
            (CONCAT(appoint_date, ' ', appoint_timein) BETWEEN '$DateStartTime' AND '$DateEndTime') 
            OR (CONCAT(appoint_date, ' ', appoint_timeout) BETWEEN '$DateStartTime' AND '$DateEndTime')
        )
";
```